# Print status after docker-compose container starts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In a docker-compose file, is it possible to wait for a container to start and then print a status?

e.g. `sleep 10 && echo started mysql on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`

A `Dockerfile` has a run command, but there isn't such a thing in a compose file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `docker-compose`, just like with a regular `docker run [...]`, you can specify `entrypoint` (cf. [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint)) and `command` (cf. [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command)).

In your case, however, what I would do is building an own Docker image based on your preferred MySQL image and `COPY` a simple entrypoint script into the image that does what you want, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 10

[command to run MySQL]

echo "Started MySQL on xyz"
```

Then specify this script as `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: (Don't forget to end the `ENTRYPOINT` script with `exec "$@"`, so it will run the `CMD`.)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is just add this to the compose file:

```
print-status:
  image: busybox
  env_file: .env
  command: "sh -c 'sleep 10 && echo \"http://localhost:${PORT}\"'"
  depends_on:
    - mysql
```

Comment: This might cause confusion in the case where your MySQL container has `restart: always` (or `on-failure`) enabled and crashes immediately for some reason. The `print-status` service will run anyway (it will not wait until the MySQL daemon _in the container_ is ready to accept connections) and you might get mislead that everything is fine due to the `echo`.

Comment: True. Good enough for my use case though.